# How to override a delete method on a Spring Data CrudRepository?

Tags: java, crud, spring-data, jpql

I have some objects I cannot delete, and must update a common field named 'deleted' instead of it. I read [there](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) that I can write generic querys, using `#{#entityName}`.
For that reason I tried to override `CrudRepository#delete(…)` method like this:

```
public interface DeleteableRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends CrudRepository<T,ID>{

    @Override
    @Query("UPDATE #{#entityName} x set x.deleted = 1 where x.id = ?1")
    public void delete(ID id);
}
```

But the I have a unit test that shows me wrong!

```
@Test
public void testDelete() {

    SomeDeleteableObject sdo = new SomeDeletableObject();
    sdo = getDeleteableRepository().create(sdo);

    Assert.assertNotNull(sdo);
    Assert.assertNotNull(sdo.getId());
    Assert.assertFalse(sdo.isDeleted());
    getDeleteableRepository().delete(sdo);

    sdo = getDeleteableRepository().findOne(sdo.getId());
    //Fails here

}
```

Isn't it possible to override `CrudRepository` methods like that?

Comment: Why you want to modify delete repository behaviour and not handle this situation in your service layer?

Comment: because if I could handle this on Repository Layer I don't need to implement extra Services or Daos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For modifying queries you need to add an `@Modifying` to the method.

Be sure you are aware of the side effects of the approach you chose:

- Executing a manipulating query is pretty much bypassing all `EntityManager` caches. Thus a subsequent `findOne(…)` might/will still return the old instance of the object you tried to delete in case the `EntityManager` had already loaded it. To prevent that, set the `clearAutomatically` flag in `@Modifying` to `true` but be aware that this will cause all pending changes being wiped out.
- For query based data manipulation *no* lifecycle callbacks will be triggered and *no* cascades will be triggered on the level of the persistence context. This means, entity listeners listening to an `@PreUpdate` event will not get notified. Also any cascade operations